Hot water heater low thermopile voltage
I Have a natural gas rheem hot water heater that does not work (no hot water).
I have replaced the pilot assembly(sp21058) and the gas control valve with replacements from the manufacturer and there is no difference then before I replaced it.
The flame goes out a few seconds after its lit and then the led flashes red twice (low thermopile voltage)
What should I do next?

Why you test before replacing parts.  Was the thermopile replaced also?

750 mV..........

Just to confirm: did the pilot assembly include a new thermopile? And you're sure it's actually a thermopile, not a thermocouple? They're different so testing/diagnostics are a little different. How long do you continue to press the pilot button after the pilot is lit? (as long as 10's of seconds may be needed.) Does the pilot continue to burn as long as you hold the button?

@crip659 the thermopile is included in the pilot assembly sp21058

@greg hill the thermopile is included in the pilot assembly sp21058

Did you check that the unit is getting enough gas?  Check the simple stuff first.
